# select a field from one row as a field from another SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry for the confusing title. I was having trouble searching for the solution I am looking for because I do not know how to summarize it in a few words.

I have a single table, table_name, with columns Indicator, ID, and Num. The Indicator is either 0 or 1 and the ID can exist up to 2 times. If the ID number exists twice, one of the indicator is 0 and the other is 1 and if the ID exists once, its indicator is 0. My query needs to be able to return 0 if the indicator for a row is 0 and Num from the matching ID with indicator 0 if the indicator is 1.

```
Indicator----ID-----Num

1-------------01----3000

0-------------01----4000

0-------------02----5000

0-------------03----100

1-------------04----400

0-------------04----200
```

RESULTS of Query

```
4000

0

0

0

200

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky, because you want to be sure not to lose any rows.  For that reason, I'm doing this with a nested `select` statement:

```
select (case when indicator = 0 then 0
             else (select t2.num from table_name t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.indicator = 0)
        end) as Val
from table_name t
```

Here is an example of it working (assuming your database supports `with`):

```
with table_name as (
      select 1 as indicator, 1 as id, 3000 as num union all
      select 0, 1, 4000 union all
      select 0, 2, 5000 union all
      select 0, 3, 100 union all
      select 1, 4, 400 union all
      select 0, 4, 200
     )
select (case when indicator = 0 then 0
             else (select t2.num from table_name t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.indicator = 0)
        end) as Val
from table_name t
```

Comment: Why can't an outer join make sure that you don't lose rows without the nasty of a nested select?

Comment: @BillGregg . . . Of course you can use an outer join.  As an outsider to this problem, the constraints of the problem make a `join` susceptible to multiplying or removing rows, if things aren't just right.  This is a case where a nested `select` removes certain concerns.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did exactly what I wanted it to. I was trying to use inner join before and I kept getting too many or too few rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when oneId.id is null the 0 else zero.num end case
from table1 zero 
left join table1 oneId
on zero.id = oneId.id
and 1 = oneId.indicator
where zero.indicator = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(t1.indicator = 0 OR t2.Num IS NULL, 0, t2.Num)
FROM table_name as t1
LEFT JOIN table_name as t2 ON(
  t1.ID = t2.ID
  AND t1.indicator != t2.indicator
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61623a/3